# How can I handle AppleScript dialog response?

Tags: applescript

I am using a script that I wrote to automatically write my dynamic IP to a .txt file but my problem is that I cannot get the dialog to close when the quit button is clicked.

```
set yn to (display dialog "Your ip has been written to the server, the application will re-run in 10 minutes if you DO NOT close this window." buttons {"Quit", "Run again"} giving up after 600)
if yn is equal to "Quit" then
quit
end if
```

Comment: I continue to be confused as to why was my question down voted?

Comment: I haven't down-voted it, but here's my guess… It's unclear from the question details how your code is failing. This phrase, in particular, is nonsensical: "my problem is that get the simplest task done as to close the applescript if dialog response is to quit."

Comment: @clozach My goodness. Thanks for not downvoting, appreciate the feedback. I was laughing hysterically at this question when I read your comment. It made absolutely no sense at all. I've come far in the last 3 years. I'm not entirely sure what I was asking way back when but I took my best guess to at least have a comprehensible question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What I ended up doing was

```
display alert "This is an alert" buttons {"No", "Yes"}
if button returned of result = "No" then
     display alert "No was clicked"
else
    if button returned of result = "Yes" then
         display alert "Yes was clicked"
    end if
end if
```

You can replace the lines "display alert "No/Yes was clicked"" with whatever code you want to run

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted ... it works ... rectifying.

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote either but here is an upvote as well as an upvote to the question all I needed was the `button returned of` from your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to figure out how to make use of `yn`'s button pressed is to look at `yn`:

```
set yn to (display dialog "Your ip has been written to the server, the application will re-run in 10 minutes if you DO NOT close this window." buttons {"Quit", "Run again"} giving up after 600)
return yn
```

You'll see that `yn` returns `{button returned:"Quit", gave up:false}`. This indicates that `yn` has a property `button returned` that you can use in your `if` statement.

Another way to figure this out is to look through the AppleScript dictionary (File > Open Dictionary...) that documents `display dialog`, which is the StandardAdditions dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

To add as an answer as the original question had a `giving up after` and I needed to do something in my script if the dialog did exceed past the timeout period.  Here is an additional option that considers the timeout:

```
set dialogTitle to "Star Wars Question"
set theDialog to display alert "Do you think Darh Maul should have his own movie?" buttons {"YES", "NO"} default button "YES" giving up after 10
if button returned of theDialog = "" then
    display notification "No decision was made, cancelled dialog" with title dialogTitle
else if button returned of theDialog = "YES" then
    display notification "I concur" with title dialogTitle
else if button returned of theDialog = "NO" then
    display notification "I find your lack of faith disturbing" with title dialogTitle
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

First, some notes:

- Even used without assigning a variable, dialogs return a `result` "record" object containing two key-value pairs: `button returned` and `gave up`.
- To get the selected button's text (other than `Cancel`), use `button returned of result`.
- When using `giving up after n`, use either `button returned of result` (with text value of `""` (empty string)) or `gave up of result` (with boolean value of `true` or `false`).
- Clicking the "Cancel" button causes an error (`number -128` or `"User canceled."`). To handle the Cancel button, use a `try` block.
- In my first example, I'm providing a `Cancel` button in multiple places. This demonstrates that the `on error` code will work regardless of which dialog in the `try` block returns the `Cancel` button. If you don't need a `Cancel`, then just provide a single button such as `buttons "OK"`.
- I'm using parens around some text in my examples, but AppleScript does *not* require these. AppleScript *does require* quotes around text.

Tested in both Monterey and High Sierra, and using [Mar10Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64850895/1107226), with fixes, as the basis for my examples to make it simple and clear...

---

```
try
  display dialog ("An example dialog.") buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} giving up after 5
  
  if button returned of result = "OK" then
    display dialog ("You clicked OK.") buttons {"OK", "Cancel"}

  else if gave up of result then
    display dialog ("You let the dialog expire.") buttons {"OK", "Cancel"}

  end if
  
-- handle the Cancel button here
on error "User canceled." -- or you can say: on error number -128

  display dialog ("You clicked Cancel.") buttons "OK"

end try
```

Same thing, stated slightly differently to show some other stuff (text without parens, `giving up after` option, generic error handling):

```
try

    -- uncomment following line to see non-Cancel-related error result ;)
    -- error "foobar!"
    display dialog "An example dialog." buttons {"OK", "Cancel"} giving up after 5
    
    if button returned of result = "OK" then
        display dialog "You clicked OK." buttons "OK"
        
    else if gave up of result then
        display dialog "You let the dialog expire." buttons "OK"
        
    end if
    
-- handle any error that might occur here;
-- errText and errNum are variable names I chose for these values
on error errText number errNum
    
    if errText is "User canceled." then -- or you can say: if errNum is -128
        display dialog "You clicked Cancel." buttons "OK"
        
    else
        display dialog "Error: " & errText & return & return & "Number: " & errNum buttons "OK"
        
    end if
    
end try
```

Answer (score -1):

```
display dialog ("An example dialog.") buttons {"Cancel", "OK"}

if button returned of result = "Button" then
 display dialog ("You clicked Button.")
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work as entered (at least as of Sept 2022). First, the `button returned of result` must match the text of the button (ie, `if button returned of result = "OK" then`). Second, clicking the "Cancel" button causes an error (`number -128` or `"User canceled."`). To handle the Cancel button with a `try` block: `try\display dialog ("An example dialog.) buttons {"Cancel", "OK"}\if button returned of result = "OK" then display dialog ("You clicked OK.") buttons "OK"\end if\on error "User canceled."\display dialog ("You clicked Cancel.") buttons "OK"\end try`